# WCF Rest Service broken after server restart

Tags: wcf, rest, post, service, get

I made a WCF Rest Service and attached it to IIS 7 on my server and it worked great. Suddenly, we had a hard drive failure and the guys who're supposed to manage the backups didn't back up anything, so we lost all our stuff on the server.

So I go about setting everything back up, and I put all the stuff on IIS. We have another WCF Rest Service that does a lot of stuff the one I made does, including a couple of the same methods for authentication and such. But now it seems that mine won't work. Our website works and our other web service works, but not this one, and I've no idea why? I set them up the exact same and I don't think I changed anything when I did it initially.

The help reference pages work, but when calling the method, I get

```
"The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."
```

I'm using the same methods as before, calling them with the same arguments, this happens for every method, regardless of GET or POST. I've used a REST extension thing in chrome to call it and the mobile app that I usually use to call it, as well as the browser and they all come up with the same error.

Here's the web.config file for it (I've tried adding a few things found on stackoverflow to get to the problem,  but it's not done anything, really).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel  >
    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    <bindings >
      <!-- pick whichever binding you want .... -->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- binding configuration with a name -->
        <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize"
            maxBufferSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800"   >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="52428800" maxStringContentLength="52428800" 
           maxArrayLength="52428800" maxBytesPerRead="52428800" maxNameTableCharCount="52428800"  />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name=""  helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800" maxBufferSize="52428800" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800"  />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

After turning tracing on, got this error from the viewer:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System 

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131076</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-27T12:15:47.5749853Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{54672f7e-5a71-4dda-92a3-f07f7c94ccb9}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="20820" ThreadID="9" /><Channel /><Computer>OHS-VMHOST-NEW</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord Severity="Error" Channel="Operational" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Handling an exception. Exception details: System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult&amp; result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult&amp; result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at OHS.MobileAssessor.Services.MobileAssessorAPIService.GetProjectData(String token)
   at SyncInvokeGetProjectData(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/mobileassessor-1-130403961472161807</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.FormatException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult&amp;amp; result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult&amp;amp; result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at OHS.MobileAssessor.Services.MobileAssessorAPIService.GetProjectData(String token)
   at SyncInvokeGetProjectData(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp;amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult&amp;amp; result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult&amp;amp; result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at OHS.MobileAssessor.Services.MobileAssessorAPIService.GetProjectData(String token)
   at SyncInvokeGetProjectData(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp;amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

As requested, my GetProjectData method (And no, it isn't managing to write anything to my event log):

```
 /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetProjectData/{token}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public GetProjectContainerResult GetProjectData(string token)
    {
        WriteLog("Getting project data...");
        GetProjectContainerResult result = new GetProjectContainerResult();
        ProjectContainer container = new ProjectContainer();

        MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults authResult = ValidateToken(new Guid(token));

        if (authResult == MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults.Success)
        {
            container.jobs = getJobs(token);
            container.buildings = getBuildings();
            container.floors = getFloors();
            container.locations = getLocations();
            result.ReturnValue = container;
            result.Result = MobileAssessorOperationResults.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (authResult)
            {
                case MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults.Error:
                    result.Result = MobileAssessorOperationResults.Error;
                    result.ResultDescription = "An error occured.";
                    result.ReturnValue = new ProjectContainer();
                    break;

                case MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults.Expired:
                    result.Result = MobileAssessorOperationResults.Failed;
                    result.ResultDescription = "The specified token has expired.";
                    result.ReturnValue = new ProjectContainer();
                    break;

                case MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults.Invalid:
                    result.Result = MobileAssessorOperationResults.Failed;
                    result.ResultDescription = "The specified token is not valid.";
                    result.ReturnValue = new ProjectContainer();
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Check the server log.

Comment: There's no log for it, I don't think. I've implemented an Event Log, but it only gets called when the methods have valid requests.

Comment: _"The server encountered an error processing the request"_. This error must be logged somewhere. Check the event logs or enable WCF tracing.

Comment: I've enabled WCF Tracing and I've got it, but it's _huge_, where do I stick it?

Comment: Open the file in the Service Trace Viewer and check where an exception occurs (red lines).

Comment: I open the XML file the trace thing gives me and it creates an svclog file, but then it said there's no trace loaded from it.

The trace file is located in the inetpub/logs/FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC1 folder. Is that the right one?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time imagining what is going on on your screen. Again, have you checked the event log first? IIS will write an error event when WCF throws an error.

Comment: Aye, it's a difficult thing to explain. I've only got the custom event log I made set up, I'm not sure what other log there is for it? Thanks for helping and getting back to me quickly though.

The Web Server Event log just tells me that the certain pools are inactive, but it says it for all of the pools, including the working ones, so I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that I hadn't enabled tracing in the specific config. I've done it now, and I've got the error mentioned above ^

Comment: The error is _"Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)"_ and occurs at `OHS.MobileAssessor.Services.MobileAssessorAPIService.GetProjectData()` where it calls the `new Guid(string)` constructor. That should tell you where to start debugging.

Comment: Hm, I put in "Pop" for the Guid, but I've done that before and it gives me an empty return. I tried what I originally had which was "W0552eac4-9427-46ac-bafb-dd6c64809ecd" which matches it and still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace from your log, I think you are having issues parsing a GUID in `MobileAssessorAPIService.GetProjectData` method

```
 at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult&amp;amp; result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult&amp;amp; result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at OHS.MobileAssessor.Services.MobileAssessorAPIService.GetProjectData(String token)
```

I would recommend that you put a break point in this method and attach a debugger to your REST service.

Based on the code you posted, the suspected line is

```
MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults authResult = ValidateToken(new Guid(token));
```

if you are not able to remotely debug this, I would recommend that you add logging just before this line to log the value of token. something like

```
logger.Log("paramater token = " + token);
```

Alternately, use wireshark to check the value of the token. once you extract the value of that guid, validate it online at http://guid.us/Test/GUID

Comment: How do I attach a debugger to it? And it does the EXACT same method in my other WCF Rest service. I tried the same argument and it works fine with it.

Comment: look at my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809865/debugging-asp-net-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis/15813759#15813759
There is a screen shot too and more links there

Comment: My VS environment is on my computer and I'm deploying to a server through Remote desktop, so I can't attach the process, can I?

Comment: with some tweaks you can... refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t(v=vs.110).aspx on how to setup remote debugging

Comment: But there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the service nor my config as they both worked before my server died and it has the same config and several of the same methods as my other rest web service that DOES work!

Comment: well based on the exception... there is a guid somewhere that's not in the proper format. can you share the code of GetProjectData data?

Comment: Sure, it's nothing special, though. Like I said, the Guid bit is on all my methods nearly and in my other service (exact same method), and it works fine. Up above ^.

Comment: i think your client is not sending a correct guid. you can either debug the client code or use wireshark and figure out the guid being passed here

Comment: Nah, the client's sending the GUID fine. I'm using the same guid that I used before my server went down. I've also tried using one from my other service. And I've tried it from the browser, too.

Comment: Did you debug the client and verify that? because if it is indeed a guid, then there is no way you should get that exception. you don't construct any other guild in your code, so this could be the only possible issue

Comment: Yeah, everything on the client side's fine. Like I said the code's not changed one bit since the server went down, and it all worked before that. That's what I thought. I thought maybe it doesn't actually pass the value through? So the token is there, but it's not passing it through to the method, if that makes sense?

Comment: yeah... for some reason the value is not being sent. you will get this exception if its blank guid

Comment: But obviously, as you can see, there's something in the link. So I've got no gosh darn clue as to why it's not working.

Comment: sorry.. I am out of ideas on this one now... somehow the value is empty or not a guid when it reaches the server... but you need to diagnose or debug that

Comment: Lol, yeah, it's an iffy one. I just can't get why it would transform the value to anything?